# SAPUI5, DatePicker-Change Event only triggered by an manual Input or by Using DatePicker setDateValue() - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, sapui5

DatePicker `change` event is only triggered by an manual input. Using `setDateValue()` the  `change` event is not triggered.

`changeValidation()`, does have all the necessary validation for any chosen input, however the function will only be triggered if an input is manually done or if `DatePicker` is used.

`this.byId("CalendarId").setDateValue(any Date);//Doesn't trigger the event at all`

How to trigger `change` event by using `setDateValue()` or by any other Scenarios?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `fireChange()`, after the `setDateValue()`. You can manually trigger the `fireChange()`.

```
var oDPicker = this.byId("CalendarId")
oDPicker.setDateValue(any Date);
oDPicker.fireChange();//Manually trigger the event
```

`fireChange()` will trigger all the validation methods as well, same as the `change` event.

[DatePicker - fireChange()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker/methods/fireChange) API